# .NET Add Functionality to Foreach Checkboxes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have checkboxes created like this:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       <tr>
        <td>
             <input type="checkbox" id="select_@item.ID" class="select" />
        </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.clientN)

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.homePage)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.clientEmail)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TrustFlow)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CitationFlow)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RI)
                </td>
```

The row is then followed by many other html helper variables so I cant use a form I don't think?

I basically want to add a delete button when clicked it deletes all the selected checkboxes, I figured I could use this jquery

```
$('.select').change(function () {
   var className = $(this).attr('class');
});
```

then perhaps create a list somehow then when the delete button is pressed it uses the list to remove the entries via a ajax post to an action result?

Is there a better or easier way to do this?

I saw a post about using a Boolean value in the checkbox or something

Comment: You have multiple issue,. the first one being duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ahh quite right if I change the class and ID around then it should be fine? I will make the edit quick

Comment: Why have an `id` at all? And you label makes no sense - clicking on it wont do anything. (and there are dozens of ways you could do this so not sure what your expecting as an answer)

Comment: @StephenMuecke well my understanding is having the ID I can use class to initiate the jquery then use the ID to add the specific ID number to a list ready for deletion? I searched how to add functionality to a checkbox but couldn't find much so been trying to write something that works

Comment: Your question is far too broad. I could write a book chapter explaining all the different ways you could approach this (why do you want to use ajax - do you want to stay on the same page when you submit? What is your POST method and what parameters are you receiving? What are you rendering in the view?)

Comment: That code has various issues as @Stephen said. You're writing a start tr tag, but you don't close it, do you want a checkbox by row, or one for cell? Perhaps you haven't published de full .cshtml. 
The id's issue that you've solved in your update. 
I don't understand why you can't use a form, put the full code to better understand. Remember that the unchecked checkboxes are not send on submit, you must store the value (on/off) on an input for example, or manage the unchecked on server. Which is the question exactly?

Comment: @Marc sorry I thought to not include the rest as I didn't want clutter the question! have included a bit more but the full cs.html is very large! I essentially want a button that deletes selected and when you press it deletes the selected checkboxes

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've used ajax before and understand javascript a bit better than I have an idea of other methods, the view would likely refresh as it would need to relist from the database but I could later do this with an action result anyways. Rendering objects from a database table

Comment: But you want to delete the checkboxes or the full row?

Comment: @Marc the full row so I could bring in item_ID then do db.remove item sorry it wasn't clear! trying to figure it all out myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. This is very simple, you must develop in order to fit your requirements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnDelete").click(function() {
    var ids = [];
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
      ids.push($(this).attr("id"));
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    })
    // ajax send id's array
  });
});
```

Comment: ahh wonderful allows me to skip a step :) thank you!